# How do I terminate a Spring application during startup?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which has some external dependencies (eg. files outside the project that need to exists in order for the application to start up properly).

One of my beans has a `@PostConstruct` method that does the initialization. I would like to exit cleanly and gracefully if the initialization is not successful - for example, the files are not found.

Calling `((ConfigurableApplicationContext)applicationContext).close();` in the `@PostConstruct` method results in

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context
```

and a chain of other Exceptions. Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: Just throw an exception...

Comment: I just call `System.exit(0)`. But I'd like a better solution.

Comment: System.exit(0) is pretty the 'only' solution to terminate....

Answer (score 3):

you can't use `System.exit(0)` in `@PostConstruct`, shutdown will waiting lock of `startupShutdownMonitor`, can't exit.

Comment: uh, sht... I liked this comment half a year ago but I forgot this important thing. Now I'm opening this page and see my own like, it's fine.

Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Sytem exit static method, it terminates the currently running Java Virtual Machine.
the code passed indicate the termination status. by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.

exp:

```
System.exit(0);
```